# How to divide progress dynamically

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

As we have seekbar, we can set its  setMax() and setProgress to the seekBar ..

```
 seekBar .setMax(audioManager
                    .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
                 
 seekBar .setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
```

Now i have created a custom View which have 1000 progress, how could i divide it dynamically for volume.

**I want to set volume max and current progress to my View**. but it must handle 1000 percentage dynamically because some mobile have 13 volume level and some have 11 or less. How could i divide them dynamically.

how could i distribute these progress

[I also check AbsSeekBar setMax method](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.java)

**Suppose**

i have 10 volume level, then as volume reaches 100 or greater i add one up level and for greater than 200 volume level go to 2 and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Math.ceil`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double)) to achieve this. For example, if I wanted to convert a value `v` in the range [0,1000] to one of 13 different discrete levels, I could do something like

```
int level = (int) Math.ceil((v/1000.0) * 13)
```

(Using 1000.0 here avoids the integer division `v/1000` returning 0 for all values of v in [0,1000].)

Then, for this case:

- `v` = 0 --> `level` = 0
- `v` = 1000 --> `level` = 13
- `v` = 437 --> `level` = `(int) Math.ceil(5.681)` = 6

etc. (Note this is actually 14 levels if you include 0, so you may want to use

```
int level = (int) Math.ceil((v/1000.0) * (n-1))
```

to get `n` levels. Note too that `Math.floor` and `Math.round` could be used in place of `Math.ceil`, depending on exactly how you want to map your range [0,1000] to each discrete volume level.)

Comment: Now i using same formula ((int)Math.ceil((progress/100.0) *15) but change 1000.0 to 100.0  And now  it is only returning 1 and 2, Can you explain me what to use when, As you have said that in some cases we have to use Math.floor and Math.round. Kindly explain me this mathematic technique.

Comment: The formula you mention in your comment should produce integer values from 0 to 15 as progress varies between 0.0 and 100.0. If you are only seeing values 0, 1 and 2, maybe progress is only varying between 0.0 and 10.0 (because 10.0/100 * 15 = 1.5 would be rounded up to 2).

Comment: As for the `floor`/`round`/`ceil` issue - you don't _have_ to use any one in particular - all will produce the same integer values as output. Which one you use will depend on how you want to handle progress values near 0.0 and 1000.0 (or whatever your current max input value is). `ceil` will tend to round up, so that you will only get 0 output if the input is exactly 0.0. `floor` will tend to round down, so you will get 0 output for a range of inputs close to and including 0.0. Round will be in between those two. Best thing to do is experiment with each to determine the best choice for UX.

Comment: thanks a lot your code is running correctly. I mistakenly assign another variable to it. Thanks